# Javascript - getting the value of child element after clicking on another child element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This must be very simple, but I still cannot figure it out... Below is an example and what I tried - all I want is to get the value of `<a id="{value}"..` after clicking on the `<div class="text"` DIV.

```css
.h {
  background: lightblue;
}

.pb {
  display: inline-block
}

.cb {
  clear: both
}

.text {
  background: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
    <div class="pb">date <a id="m75813" href="#m75183">#</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" onclick="alert(parentNode.parentElement.firstChild.childNodes[1].a.id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying this somewhat convoluted way of getting the ID? It seems like if this code is being programmatically generated, you could just generate the appropriate value in the sibling element...

Comment: I just wanted to create an element (button) when clicking within this div=text area..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the element has an ID, you can just look it up by that ID. IDs have to be unique *(but keep reading, I suspect you don't want to do that)*:

```
alert(document.getElementById('m75813').id);
```

```css
.h {
  background: lightblue;
}

.pb {
  display: inline-block
}

.cb {
  clear: both
}

.text {
  background: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
    <div class="pb">date <a id="m75813" href="#m75183">#</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('m75813').id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>

</article>
```

**but** if you have lots of these with various IDs and it's the ID you're trying to find, you can do it by going up to the parent node and using `querySelector` to find the `a` element:

```
alert(this.parentNode.querySelector('a').id);
```

```css
.h {
  background: lightblue;
}

.pb {
  display: inline-block
}

.cb {
  clear: both
}

.text {
  background: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
    <div class="pb">date <a id="m75813" href="#m75183">#</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.querySelector('a').id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>

</article>
<article>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
    <div class="pb">date <a id="m54684" href="#m54684">#</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.querySelector('a').id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m54684"] (ie. 'm54684') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>

</article>
```

In both cases, I would suggest modern event handling rather than using `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers. For example: Let's assume all those `article` elements are in some kind of container. We can hook `click` on the container and then find which `div` the click passed through, and find the `a` related to that `div`:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = e.target;
  while (element != this) {
    if (element.matches("div.text")) {
      alert(element.parentNode.querySelector("a").id);
      break;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
});
```

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var element = e.target;
  while (element != this) {
    if (element.matches("div.text")) {
      alert(element.parentNode.querySelector("a").id);
      break;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
});
```

```css
.h {
  background: lightblue;
}

.pb {
  display: inline-block
}

.cb {
  clear: both
}

.text {
  background: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <article>
    <div class="h">
      <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
      <div class="pb">date <a id="m75813" href="#m75183">#</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
    </div>

  </article>
  <article>
    <div class="h">
      <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
      <div class="pb">date <a id="m54684" href="#m54684">#</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
      After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="54684"] (ie. '54684') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
    </div>

  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: For the first, you could just do `alert('m75813')` and save yourself the lookup ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Hence continuing the thought. :-) And there is a **slight** difference: The code above will throw if the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div class="text" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('m75813').id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your queries are returning *text nodes* (which includes whitespace like newlines) as well as HTML nodes, so your elements aren't at the index you expect. `querySelector('a')` is the simpler approach, but if you *did* want to select your target via it's place in the DOM structure, you could use `firstChildElement` and `children` instead of `firstChild` and `childNodes`, respectively, because they exclude text nodes:

`this.parentElement.firstElementChild.children[1].firstElementChild.id`

```css
.h {
  background: lightblue;
}

.pb {
  display: inline-block
}

.cb {
  clear: both
}

.text {
  background: #ffc;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="pb">user</div> &nbsp;
    <div class="pb">date <a id="m75813" href="#m75183">#</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="text" onclick="alert(this.parentElement.firstElementChild.children[1].firstElementChild.id);">
    After clicking on the yellow background, the value from [a id="m75813"] (ie. 'm75813') should apppear. Sentence text.<br> Other sample.<br> Hello world.
  </div>

</article>
```